# Converting current time to this format: "2017-04-25T17:12:42+01:00"

Tags: java, simpledateformat

How can I convert current time to this format:

```
 "2017-04-25T17:12:42+01:00"
```

The closest I could get is this:

```
"2017-05-16T19:58:21+0100"
```

by using this format:

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ").format(new Date())
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should use the modern Java 8 java.time package, more specifically [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html), the [ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME).

From the docs:

> public static final DateTimeFormatter ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME
>
> The ISO date-time formatter that formats or parses a date-time with an
>   offset, such as '2011-12-03T10:15:30+01:00'.

Working code:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    ZonedDateTime date = ZonedDateTime.now();
    String text = date.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
    System.out.println(text);
  }
}
```

Result:

```
> run Main
2017-05-19T13:03:16.167+02:00
```

Comment: Simpler: `OffsetDateTime.now().toString()`. Then you don’t need the formatter. (I still upvoted for the use of the modern classes.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use "**yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssXXX**" as pattern instead of **yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ**, see the examples [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

`ZZZ` is RFC 822 time zone like this:   `-0800;`

`XXX` is ISO 8601 time zone like this:  `-08:00;`

Use `XXX` if want to second foramt and don't want use `ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME`, for example, want to display `“01/15/2000T14:44:59-08:00”:`

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy'T'HH:mm:ssXXX").format(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

For this specific format you can simply use [java.time.OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html), available since Java-8 :

`OffsetDateTime.now().toString();`

Answer (score -1):

SimpleDateFormat will do a thing for you

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

formatter.format(date);
```

Comment: (1) I don’t see how it solves the problem of the colon not being in the result? (2) These days we should no longer use `SimpleDateFormat` if we can avoid it. It has been outdated for a couple of years now.