# How to format today's day with SimpleDateFormat?

Tags: java, date, datetime, simpledateformat

Hi I am trying to get today's date but not getting proper output

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY");
System.out.println("TODAY  :" + sdf.format(new Date()));
```

output

```
TODAY  :142/05/2017
```

Year and month coming properly but why the day is coming like this

Comment: It's `dd/MM/yyyy`

Comment: DD is day in year: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: See this you will surely get the ans
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4772425/change-date-format-in-a-java-string

Comment: I am sure this question is a duplicate. I don’t think the link in the previous comments is the best, but I have not found a better one myself yet, so please check it out.

Comment: While the answers given here are correct, the better way to format today’s date is with the newer and more programmer-friendly classes described in JSR-310: `LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy"))`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [“EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy” date format to java.sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43933597/eee-mmm-dd-hhmmss-zzz-yyyy-date-format-to-java-sql-date).

Comment: Or possible duplicate of [Converting current time to this format: “2017-04-25T17:12:42+01:00”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44067846/converting-current-time-to-this-format-2017-04-25t1712420100).

Answer (score 4):

`D`  is Day in year
`d` is Day in month
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

EDIT: Also as @JeremyP noticed you can use `yyyy`for getting year 'cause
`Y` is Week year

Comment: Also should lowercase the `YYYY`

Answer (score 1):

Oracle:

> SimpleDateFormat is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates
>   in a locale-sensitive manner. It allows for formatting (date -> text),
>   parsing (text -> date), and normalization.

- simple **y**     Year        -Year   *(1996; 96)*
- capital **Y**    Week year   -Year   *(2009; 09)*
- simple  **d**    Day in month    -Number     *(10)*
- capital **D**    Day in year     -Number     *(189)*
- capital **M**    Month in year   -Month  *(July; Jul; 07)*

In your code:

`SimpleDateFormat("DD/MM/YYYY")`

Should be:

`SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy")`

refer [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for more info

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my problem.

Comment: You are welcome and if got something in my answer it is lot to me.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
`D` is for the day in the year and `Y` is for the week year.

You need to use `d` (lower case) for `Day in month` and `y` (lower case) for `Year`

This you pattern should look like:

```
 DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `DD` with `dd` and `YYYY` to `yyyy`. MM is in capital and others are in lowercase.

> d = day of the month
>
> D = day of the year
>
> M = month in year
>
> m = minute in hour
>
> y = Year
>
> Y = Week year

```
private static final DateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
System.out.println("TODAY  :" + sdf.format(new Date()));
```